# Using spel with Hibernate Table and flyway

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-el

Given such a SPEL expression in application.yml file for a spring boot app -

```
database:
      schema: '#{"${ENV_VAR:}".equals("")?"DEMO":"DEMO_${ENV_VAR:}"}'
```

Following works in code and it prints substituted value like DEMO_XYZ / DEMO if ${ENV_VAR} = XYZ

```
@Value("${database.schema}")
private String schema;
```

But a Hibernate JPA entity with Table annotation is not able to take the SPEL enabled variable here as schema -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A", schema="${database.schema}") // prints whole spel expression here 
public class TableA { ...
```

Even below is not able to use substituted value for SPEL using default-schema -

```
spring:  
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_schema: ${database.schema} // prints whole value here as well
```

Seems like flyway is not able to use a SPEL variable as well defined already in application.yml

```
spring:  
  flyway:
    jdbc-url: ...
    schemas: ${database.schema}
```

Any way for `hibernate.default_schema` and `flyway.schemas` to accept a SPEL expression like `${database.schema}` in same YML ?

Comment: @table and hibernate props are not part of spring thus resolution does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by programatically creating Hibernate JPA beans and Flyway beans like below instead of using YML since only @Value annotations is able to read SPEL

```
database:
      schema: '#{"${ENV_VAR:}".equals("")?"DEMO":"DEMO_${ENV_VAR:}"}'
```

Database config

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.xyz"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.xyz"})
public class DbConfig
{
    @Value("${database.schema}")
    private String schema; 

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        return sessionFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager()
    {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public HikariConfig hikariConfig()
    {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("net.client.jdbc.Driverx");
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(url);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("user", user);
        props.put("password", password);
        props.put("db", db);
        props.put("schema", schema);  // SCHEMA is from SPEL
        hikariConfig.setDataSourceProperties(props);
        return hikariConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(HikariConfig hikariConfig)
    {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource snowflakeDataSource)
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.xyz");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", schema);
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }
```

Flyway Config

```
    @Value("${database.schema}")
    private String schema;

    @Bean
    public Flyway flyway(DataSource dataSource)
    {
        Flyway flyWay = Flyway.configure()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .locations("classpath:/somefolder/migrations")
            .schemas(schema)  // SCHEMA is from SPEL
            .baselineVersion("1.0")
            .sqlMigrationPrefix("V")
            .sqlMigrationSuffixes(".sql")
            .placeholders(Map.of("key1", value1,
                "key2", value2))
            .placeholderReplacement(true)
            .placeholderPrefix("%")
            .placeholderSuffix("%")
            .load();
        flyWay.migrate();
        return flyWay;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot does not actually support SpEL in `application.yml`.

If you inject the `Environment` and

```
String property = env.getProperty("database.schema");
```

you will see that the placeholders are resolved, but not the SpEL.

`@Value` must have some additional logic to resolve SpEL further downstream.

Comment: actually needed to use different schemas being passed an env variable using a ternary with flyway and hibernate, is there any other way in yaml to pass conditional expressions in those fields if not using Spel ?